# Grails Rules Update

Tags: grails, groovy, rules

Is there a newer set of grails rules than the Nemo groovy/grails profile rules?

http://nemo.sonarqube.org/rules_configuration/index/118

Rules are a bit dated, such as

> Grails Public Controller Method
>
> Checks for public methods on Grails controller classes. Static methods are ignored.

- Sonar 3.7.4
- Groovy Plugin 1.0-spantree-SNAPSHOT
- Sonar Eco System 1.4
- Various versions of Grails 2.x.x

Comment: Is this going to require and upgrade of the Groovy plugin?http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Groovy+Plugin  I believe the span tree plugin is .6 Groovy plugin wrapper, meaning codenarc 0.17.  Upgrading to Groovy 1.0 plugin should give me codenarc .20 with some updated rules, but where can I get the updated profile?

Comment: I look at https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-groovy/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/sonar/plugins/groovy/profile-sonar-way.xml  which won't import into a sonar profile.  Do I need the new plugin setup?

Comment: Had to "restore" profile-sonar-way.xml from the above github project, which worked. Seems an odd process. I would expect more of a defined process from the sonarqube site. It may exist but I can't find it specified.

Comment: For example, where are the JavaScript rules sets housed? Under the github project? No. So where?

Answer (score 0):

Restore the profile-sonar-way.xml from

https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-groovy/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/sonar/plugins/groovy/profile-sonar-way.xml

You may have to rename the existing profile before importing.